# In Unity3D How can I get position of GameObject after rotation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

If I'm looking for position vector w.r.t the world coordinate system.

Is it `transform.position` or is it `transform.rotation.inverse() * transform.position`

If the object doesnt physically move, but is rotated, does the transform.position value change?

Thanks,

Comment: It does not change.  transform.position refers to the location of the pivot point (in world space) of that object, so rotations using pivot will not change the position.  If you were to rotate based on a different point, then the position would likely change, eg. planet rotating around a body.

Comment: If your object visually moves when you rotate it that would mean your pivot point is not where it should be .. e.g. the mesh not correctly centered on that pivot